# How does Spring Boot 2.3.X Maven Project use Parent POM?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle

I got to know that Spring Boot 2.3.X is using Gradle.

If so, how does a Maven-based Spring Boot  2.3.X  project uses a parent pom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.3 uses Gradle for its own build but applications using Spring Boot can continue to use Maven (or any other build system they were using before). Spring Boot 2.3 publishes the same artifacts (jar files, pom files, etc) as Spring Boot 2.2 so a Maven-based project can continue to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as its parent pom.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [spring initialiser](https://start.spring.io/), you can find the option to build with gradle. All the parent dependencies will be automatically added by the initialiser into the build.gradle file.

Maven based pom.xml shall also be created using same spring initializer by choosing appropriate properties in the initializer page.